# Сборка GTK+ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gtk

Пытаюсь собрать GTK+ для Windows. Скачал [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) при попытке собрать вышла такая ошибка

```
**Error**: You must have `glib' installed. You can get it from: ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/gtk
```

Стал собирать glib по инструкции, а там вот это

```
make: *** Не заданы цели и не найден make-файл.  Останов.
```

это первое, что я собираю, подскажите как собрать и подключить.

Comment: Либо не выполнили `configure`, либо он свалился с ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

Если это перввая сборка воспользуйся утилитой pacman в MSYS2

> pacman -S gtk+-3